# Urban Airship amount of files required to set "alias" for token

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am making my first app which will use push notifications. I have decided to use Urban Airship to facilitate the server side of this process. So currently I have set up an account/certificates/iOS API and am able to send push notifications to a device/devices from Urban Airship.

I want to set an alias for the token that is created on each device. I know that I need to create the alias in my code and send it through Urban Airships API back to them. The question I have is what files do I need to include in my project to set the alias and return it. I have looked on Urban Airships site and the only instructions I see are for files and frameworks to include for using AirMail. I don't think I need all of that and am wondering if anyone else has been through this process and would be able to shed some light. I am not an expert programmer, but I do have a few apps under my belt.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [static library developed by Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/docs/airship_lib.html), or you can roll a simple registration library yourself. Given your question, you would probably do better with the first option. The documentation is quite extensive and contains a nice walkthrough for integrating the library and registering your devices, including the aliases. Did you read it?

Comment: Yes I have. I do seem to be having some trouble getting my project to recognize UAirship.h when I add a path ../Airship/ to my project header search path. It doesn't seem to find the files. I am putting them in my project folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tick the “Recursive” checkbox? Header management in Xcode is a mess, [I wish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758540) we could use frameworks. If you don’t succeed, Google for some Xcode library integration tutorial to wrap your head around the process a bit more.

Comment: I did set it to recursive. Thanks very much for your input. I will try to google as you suggest.