# Can I use the new @import directive to import custom frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was happy to see the new `@import` directive in Objective-C, but I lived under the impression it could not be currently used to import custom frameworks ([one source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7)). But I have just created a custom Cocoa Framework in Xcode 6 ([are these supported now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758540/why-aren%E2%80%99t-private-frameworks-supported-on-ios)) and I can `@import` it just fine. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `@import` in Xcode 6. From [New Features in Xcode 6 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html):

> **User-defined modules**. Developers are now able to define modules for
>   their own Objective-C code, making it easier than ever for them to
>   share frameworks across all their projects. By combining user-defined
>   modules with Swift’s automatic creation of modules, the two languages
>   work together seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

There are more details in the WWDC 2014 video "What's New in LLVM", page 25 of the PDF:

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/417xx2zsyyp8zcs/417/417_whats_new_in_llvm.pdf?dl=1