# How do I solve class name conflicts when creating an iOS framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, linker

I am writing an iOS framework `Foo` that depends on a static third-party library `Lib` and have problems getting the linking right.

If `Foo` was a static library, I would *not* link it against `Lib`, and only link the master project against both of them. But this approach does not seem to work with a framework: the linker complains about missing symbols from `Lib`.

So I took the other approach and linked `Foo` against `Lib`. Now the linker is happy, but there’s an obvious catch: if the master project uses `Lib` for its own reasons and links both against `Foo` and `Lib`, I get duplicate symbols:

```
Class <Something> is implemented in both <Here> and <There>.
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I know I can stop linking the app against `Lib` and all will be fine, but I’d like to get things right. How?

Comment: Is this a dynamic framework? (support of which is only now being introduced into iOS AFAIK).

Comment: It’s what Apple calls “private framework” on OS X. A framework that’s bundled inside the app’s package, not linked to its binary. Which probably means yes, it’s a dynamic framework. (Here’s a [question about the status of these frameworks on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758540).)

Comment: If that's the case then 1) you'll need to check support for the version of iOS you want to support (up to know there was only support for static frameworks which are glorified static libraries with associated resources). 2) duplicate symbols don't make sense as the binaries are completely separate (think .exe and .dll).

Comment: Oh, it’s the runtime complaining, not the linker. Should have been obvious to me, I only get the warning at runtime. I’ll edit the question.

Comment: Ah I've seen that before and it sent a shiver down my spine (as it seems very insidious).  However I cannot remember what the solution was :)

Comment: @zoul i am struggling with this for some time, did you manage to find a solution? the accepted answer here dont seem to work. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can’t remember solving the issue, I have probably side-stepped it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working for a *framework*, though the docs say it should work for a static library as well.

What I did is link the master project against both `Foo` and `Lib` as you say. Now `Foo` has "missing symbol" errors. Select the `Foo` target and go to Other Linker Flags. Add `-weak_framework Lib` and presto! the linker will stop complaining. The duplicate symbol runtime errors go away.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-107026):

> The `-weak_framework` option tells the linker to weakly link all symbols in the named framework. If you need to link to a library instead of a framework, you can use the `-weak_library` linker command instead